# How to set ToggleButton width to the wider of textOn and textOff values?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, togglebutton

A [`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) widget changes size when the checked state is toggled. For example, if the `textOn` value is "true" and the `textOff` value is "not sure call me later", a checked state toggle causes the button width to change dramatically.

It would be nice to set the width of a `ToggleButton` to the maximum of the two content-wrapped widths created by `textOn` and `textOff`.

Is there a preferred way to maintain constant `ToggleButton` width? Is the best way to simply call `getWidth()`, then `toggle()`, then `getWidth()` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because its a button with just two strings, there is no harm in providing the width in the XML itself according to the larger string.

But if you want to calculate the width of the strings, it's simple:

```
Paint paint = toggleButton.getPaint();
float length = paint.measureText(YOUR_STRING);
```

This gives you the width of the string it would take on the screen. Now set the width of the toggle button via `LayoutParams`.

Lets say parent layout of your toggle button is LinearLayout.
so it should go like:
*toggleButton.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(WIDTH_YOU_CALCULATED, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*

This will set the width and height of your ToggleButton to what you calculated.

Answer (score 3):

I needed this for my toggle button and improved it a little.
I removed layout settings and included the padding. If you do not take the padding into account, your string will be wrapped inside the button.

```
    ToggleButton tglBtn = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleBtn);
    tglBtn.setWidth((int) tglBtn.getPaint().measureText("Longest String")+tglBtn.getPaddingLeft()+tglBtn.getPaddingRight());
```

Comment: I would note that the text with the most characters (longest string) is not necessarily the text that has the largest width; See for example `iiiiiii` vs `MMMM`.